# ObjectId in simpleSchema or collection2

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

I am just playing around with meteor and started using simple-schema and collection2. I moved from mongoose and node so my question could be a bit noob, so bear with me.

In mongoose I could just add a type called schema.ObjectId,in some field to emulate reference, but I don't see any such implication in collection2.
Is there any quick solution for that?

Is using type: String a good idea for this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id` is the type that should be used for mongo id fields for all typical cases.